# How To Make a Score Event Script for On-click game using purely HTML, css and Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, events, onclick

I need help on my game, in this chase I need help for On-click event. I have a image that for each time I click on it I get 1 score point. I need help to create this quite basic event or someone who be kind enough to write a script for me.
I created a basic code for the clicker game:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>My Work</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <img id="nokia" src="phone.jpg" />
    </body>
</html>
```

I haven't made that much progress as you can see, I need help with a on-click event in either html or in JavaScript also a score board system would be a nice touch however I can probably figure this out.

I got a friend to write some code but time was limited I got a half done code if you like to finish it or to tell me what he was trying to do here is that code:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>My Work</title>
        <script>
            (function() {
                var score = 0;
                var phone = document.getElementById("nokia");
                phone.onclick=function(){
                    score++;
                    output = document.getElementById("score");
                    output.innerHTML = score;
                };
            })();
        </script>  
    </head>
    <body>
        <img id="nokia" src="phone.jpg" />
        <div id="score"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

All help is greatly appreciated! :)

Comment: are you willing to use jquery our plain javacsript?

Answer (score 0):

You would do something like this (plain js)

```
document.getElementById('nokia').onclick=function(){
    var score = parseInt(document.getElementById("score").innerHTML);
    score++;
    document.getElementById("score").innerHTML = score;
}
```

Here a full example as fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/sbunu38g/

Note: You will need to set the content of your score div to 0 at the beginning. Otherwise you will receive NaN after clicking the image

Update: 
As asked in comments - to be able to use this in your header element you will need to wrap window.onload function around it. By this you will ensure the needed elements are loaded before trying to attack the onclick eventhandler

```
window.onload = function() {
    document.getElementById('nokia').onclick=function(){
        var score = parseInt(document.getElementById("score").innerHTML);
        score++;
        document.getElementById("score").innerHTML = score;
    }
};
```

Comment: Seems like I can't make it work or either the code is put in wrong. here is what I did with your code you posted @FrankProvost `<html>
  <head>
    <title>My Work</title>
    <script>
    document.getElementById('nokia').onclick=function(){
      var score = parseInt(document.getElementById("score").innerHTML);
      score++;
      document.getElementById("score").innerHTML = score;
  }
</script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <img id="nokia" src="phone.jpg" />
    <div id="score">0</div>
  </body>
</html>
`

Comment: Seems like the commenting system just trashed everything I wrote in to a pile of text, tl:tr

Comment: you will need to place the script in your body. To be more specific you will need to place it at the end of your body (under your needed html elements (the image and the score) - if you would like to place it in your header you could wrap window.onload around it. This would look something like this: window.onload = function() { document.get... };